# margin of error trying to check if a point lays on line

Tags: c#, mathematics, xna-4.0

Working with floating point values it is as easy as breathing to run on approximation errors by comparing quantities which should be the same. I want to know if there is a way built in some MSDN (or even external) library for c# to ignore the problem.

An example could be: more than comparing 2 float values like this

```
if(myVector3.X == anotherVector3.X)
```

I would appreciate something like this

```
if(myVector3.X.isInTheNeighbourhood(anotherVector3.X))
```

This is not well-written, I know. That is just to simplify the explaination. What I am exactly doing is checking if a point (`Vector3`) lays on line segment. So basically the calculations I make are nothing more than

```
(x - x1)/(x2 - x1) = (y - y1)/(y2 - y1) = (z - z1)/(z2 - z1)
```

But these values won't be always the same, so I need to write down some code which includes a sort of tolerance a sort of Neighbourhood mathematical concept to accept values close enought to the line.

Hope that I made myself clear.
Has anyone a solution for this?

Comment: Your question mentions a line segment, but your equation is for a line without limits. Which one is it you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to take into consideration the floating point error you need to do the following:

```
\#define ERR 1e-9
if( fabs (myVector3.X - anotherVector3.X)  <= ERR )
```

Keep in mind that this kind of approximation changes the geometrical properties of the shape, for instance this can generate fat planes/lines. a case where a line or a plane no more has zero width. But as far as you don't need exact calculations such as those needed in geometry analysis it's fine for a game. Here is a link where it [explains the problem in using floating points in geometry](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html).

[image]

There are other methods to solve the error problem and get exact results, but they are far too complex or far too slow. So non of them from my experience with geometry fit the requirements of the real time video games.

Comment: Your answer is kinda complete and sounds really practical. Indeed what I'm talking about is a real time videogame. Therefore, if I aim just to slightly alterate the position of moving objects it would be correct to say that I would not notice any apparent noisy movement?

Comment: @Leggy7 if we are talking about an error of around 1e-9 or even higher no you won't notice any difference. Games aren't exact science so unless you want to simulate sth (and even that have error) it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds me to me like you need a [Ray-Sphere Intersection test](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/287024-simple-raysphere-collision/).

Your sphere would be defined by the point and the radius as your margin of error.